# Fancybox - declaring size in link

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

Due to the system i'm having to build a site in templates are extremely restrictive so I don't have much control.

My question is:

Is it possible with fancybox to set the width and height in the link?

e.g.

`<a href="iframelocation" class="fancybox 480 320">Click here"</a>`

Thanks in advance.

PVS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the values in `data-` attributes. (assuming you are using jQuery 1.4.3 or greater)

```
<a href="iframelocation" class="fancybox" data-width="480" data-height="320">Click here"</a>

$("a.fancybox").each(function(){
   var $a = $(this);
   var h = $a.data("height")
   var w = $a.data("width");
   $a.fancybox({
            'width' : w, 
            'height': h
   });
});
```

Comment: Does jQuery automatically parse `data-*` attributes?

Comment: It will as long as you are using jQuery 1.4.3 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

```
<a href="iframelocation" class="fancybox" data-width="480" data-height="320">Click here"</a>
```