# Dynamically set fancybox 3 iframe size

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

When dealing with *dynamically* sizing the **iframe** in fancybox, I accidentally found that setting `data-width` and `data-height` on the `[data-fancybox]` is helpful after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378565/fancybox-declaring-size-in-link).

Exmaple HTML element:

```
<a data-fancybox data-width="<?= $banner_width; ?>" data-height="<?= $banner_height; ?>"  data-src="example.com" href="javascript:;">example.com</a>
```

and js:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function ( instance, slide ) {
        $('body').find('.fancybox-content').css({"width": slide.opts.width + "px", "height": slide.opts.height + "px"});
    }
});
```

What I couldn't figure out is that there is no explanation of `data-width` and `data-height` usage on HTML element from fancybox documentation (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**NOTE: these two code snippets above do work for me, but they have to work together, it wouldn't work if one of them is taken off.**

Can anyone explain that a little bit for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Properties - `data-width` and `data-height` - are used to tell the script real dimension of the image. The script then can calculate position and start zooming thumbnail while real image is still loading.

See documentation -  http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#images

These properties are not used anywhere else.

You can use `{ iframe : { css : { width: '', height : '' } } }`  to set iframe element width/height, but there is no option to change iframe content.

Comment: Hey Janis, thanks for the reply, but I was using iframe instead of image. I think I found the answer, I will post my answer later on.

Comment: I just tried to explained that they are not intended for iframes, they are used only for images.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that, it's my bad, sorry. I thought _enter_ will go to next line but it actually submits my answer :( 

`{ iframe : { css : { width: '', height : '' } } }` does change the iframe size, but it will only change **once** when the fancybox object was created, which means it makes every iframe on my page fixed size and that is not what I want. As you can see, the `data-width` and `data-height` were generated from PHP code in my case, so I want every iframe has a different size :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [fancybox 3 documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options), they do offer a way to set our own custom options by creating `data-options` attribute. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
<a data-fancybox 
   data-options='{"caption" : "My caption", "src : "iframe.html"}' href="javascript:;">
   Open external page using iframe
</a>
```

You can see the value of these options by `console.info( slide.opts )` from the callback function like `onComplete` (`slide` is one argument in the callback function ).

Not surprisingly, these two snippets are the same:

```
<a data-fancybox data-width="<?= $banner_width; ?>" data-height="<?= $banner_height; ?>"  data-src="example.com" href="javascript:;">example.com</a>

<a data-fancybox data-options='{"width" : "<?= $banner_width; ?>", "height" : data-height="<?= $banner_height; ?>", "src" : "example.com" }' href="javascript:;">example.com</a>
```

So, in my javascript, I use `slide.opts.width` to get the value from `data-width` and `slide.opts.height`to get the height from `data-height`, that is how my width and height value get passed from backend to frontend.

Since these two values are processed in `afterLoad` callback, so every iframe will be initiated with different width and height.